# Сервер для игры на webgl

Tags: node.js, webgl, javascript, php

Игра браузерная, многопользовательская на webgl, с большой посещаемостью

На каком языке и по какой технологии писать серверную часть

node.js php или?

Если участвовали в таких проектах напишите что использовали

Comment: На node.js лучше будет. Всё потому, что он быстрее и, собственно, предназначен для долгоживущих приложений, а php - нет. ИМХО.

Comment: вот VenZell навел шороху -- повытаскивал мертвяков прошлогодних целый шкаф :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот статья о похожем проекте - http://habrahabr.ru/post/182678/

Тут уже спрашивали - http://toster.ru/q/74272, http://toster.ru/q/36581

А вот это я бы посоветовал лично, сам пользую - http://shustoff.su/blog/javascript/meteor-js-framework-for-create-real-time-apps

Comment: @ICE, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от структуры мультиплеера, если все игроки в одном мире и пересекаются друг с другом то websoket's

Если разбивка на комнаты и присутствует динамика в движении и т.п то WebRtc (RTCDataChannel)

Если запросы редкие и нет нужды в вечном коннекте (карточные игры, бильярд и т.п) то http сервер (php, node.js, Java, да что угодно)